# The opposite of String.Normalize(): compose string?

Tags: c#, string, cjk

Using the code below, I could decompose "고양이" into its parts "ㄱㅗㅇㅑㅇㅇㅣ". But how can I do the opposite? I want to get "고양이" from "ㄱㅗㅇㅑㅇㅇㅣ". I looked into `NormalizationForm` and there seemed to be no entry for composition, and passing no argument for `Normalize()` did not compose it either.

```
var text = "고양이";
var a = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
foreach(var c in a)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(c);
}

text = "ㄱㅗㅇㅑㅇㅇㅣ";
a = text.Normalize();
foreach (var c in a)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(c);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know much about the Korean alphabet, so I can't help.  But I'm curious: what do you mean by "decompose into its parts"?  Could you help explain (to a 7-bit ASCII/English speaking kind of guy like me)?

Comment: @paulsm4 The Korean alphabet has the properties of both the Alphabet and Hiragana. Like the Alphabet, each "part" denotes one sound, and there are 24 "parts". In Hiragana, each letter denotes one syllable, so Hiragana has 50 letters (lucky that Japanese doesn't have a lot of syllables). The Korean alphabet parts are always combined to form a letter that denotes one syllable like Hiragana. For example, two parts "ㄱ" (k) and "ㅗ"(o) can be combined to form one letter "고" which denotes one syllable "ko" like Hiragana こ.

Comment: How would it know, for example, that the first resulting character shouldn't be "공" from "ㄱㅗㅇ", considering that the decomposed characters don't have separators? Granted, it lacks an initial consonant for the next syllable, but then should it consider that an error, or backtrack to try to convert the final consonant from the previous syllable to an initial consonant on the second?

Comment: @madreflection Well, if I passed "ㄱㅗㅇ", then it should be "공", but I passed "ㄱㅗㅇㅑㅇㅇㅣ", and if the first 3 parts are combined into one letter, then the second letter must start with the fourth part which is "ㅑ". This is impossible in Korean, because a letter cannot start with a vowel like "ㅑ".

Comment: `NormalizationForm.FormKC`  appears to do what you want.

Comment: @madreflection  The inventor probably created ㅋ(strong k) by simply adding one line (to mean "stronger") to ㄱ(soft k) , but they have been considered two different parts. A Korean keyboard has separate keys for each of them. There is "ㄲ" which is two ㄱ, and I think I saw some third-party IME's that combined "ㄱㄱ" into "ㄲ", but Microsoft's Korean IME doesn't do that. Most Koreans don't type ㄲ by pressing ㄱ twice, but at once by pressing shift + ㄱ.  I can think of very few cases where there can be two possible ways of composition. Maybe there is none, if we consider the Korean language.

Comment: @madreflection  I have tried `FormKC` and it had one issue. ㅇ was originally two completely different parts (but in similar shapes). A circle meant "empty" or "there is no consonant here", and a circle with a dot attached denoted the "ng" sound (as in "sing"). Later, people began to use the same circle for both of them, so today, Korean keyboards have only one ㅇ. In "ㄱㅗㅇㅑㅇㅇㅣ", the first/third ㅇ's mean "no consonant" and the 2nd ㅇ denotes "ng". That is, it is supposed to be "고양이"(ko yang i), and both "양" (yang) and "이" (i) have no starting consonant. With `FormKC`, "ㄱㅗㅇㅑㅇㅇㅣ" became "고야ᄋ이".

Comment: That was my concern, based solely on intuition, that it wouldn't see the boundary correctly.  I was wrong about exactly *how* it would fail, though. I assumed that it might be greedy (in the way that regex is "greedy" unless you add `?` to make it not greedy, e.g. `.*?`) but in fact it failed to include the final consonant (ng) on the second syllable.